# Field memberRepo in (...) required a bean of type that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

I'm working on a Spring Boot project. Implementing Back-End code with the data, I've got an error.
  Before working on the security, that is, when I've just done with the MemberRepository, MemberService, and MemberController, it worked well. After I worked on the security, that kind of error occurs.

I'm using IntelliJ as the IDE, and the methods were MySQL, Java, Spring Boot, Spring Security, and Maven. The OS is Mac.

This is a part of MemberRepository.java code:

```
package com.springboot.reserving.member;

import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Select;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Repository
public interface MemberRepository extends CrudRepository<Member, Long> { ... }
```

This is a part of MemberService.java code:

```
package com.springboot.reserving.member;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Service
public class MemberService {

    @Autowired
    MemberRepository memberRepository;

    ...
}
```

This is CustomUserDetailService.java code:

```
package com.springboot.reserving.member;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    MemberRepository memberRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return Optional.ofNullable(memberRepo.read(username))
                .filter(m -> m != null)
                .map(m -> new SecurityMember(m)).get();
    }
}
```

The error message was:

```
Description:

Field memberRepo in com.springboot.reserving.member.CustomUserDetailsService required a bean of type 'com.springboot.reserving.member.MemberRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.springboot.reserving.member.MemberRepository' in your configuration.
```

What should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reason is that spring doesn't create Spring Data Repository out of the interface.

In a nutshell, spring data project generates a "proxy" in runtime - an implementation of the interface that will contain all the required methods for working with the database.

In order to make is possible you should enable this proxy generation for you DAOs:

This can be done with:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.springboot.reserving.member")
```

So make sure you have this annotation on spring boot application class.